# How to get selected cell values of last row from SQL database into two labels?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to get values from selected columns of the last row into label 1 and label 2 when the form is loaded from a SQL database. My code is not working. How can I do this?
My code is here:

```
Private Sub getvalue()
    Dim strConn = "server= PANKAJ\SQLEXPRESS; database = pankaj billing software; integrated security=true"
    Dim sqlConn = New SqlConnection(strConn)

    sqlConn.Open()

    Dim sqlcmd As New SqlCommand("select 22ktrate, 21ktrate from ratedata where max(rateid) = @rateid", sqlConn)
    Dim myreader As SqlDataReader

    myreader = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader()
    myreader.Read()

    If myreader.HasRows Then
        Label1.Text = myreader.Item("22ktrate")
        Label2.Text = myreader.Item("21ktrate")
    End If

    sqlConn.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: you have to iterate at all the rows, get the values of the column you need and add them to your label. you can actually do it with `while reader.read()`

Comment: my form has no datagrid. i just want last row two selected column values from sql database in two labels of form.

Comment: wait.. can you clarify what you meant by `last row two selected column`? What does the user have to select?

Comment: There's no ORDER BY clause, meaning "last" in this context is undefined. You're just as well off taking the first, if you even get more than one record in the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The big thing I noticed is nothing sets the `@rateid` parameter.

```
Private Sub getvalue()
    Dim conn As String = "server= PANKAJ\SQLEXPRESS; database = pankaj billing software; integrated security=true"
    Dim sql As String = "select [22ktrate], [21ktrate] from ratedata where max(rateid) = @rateid"

    Using sqlConn As New SqlConnection(conn), _
          sqlcmd As New SqlCommand(sql, sqlConn)

        'This was missing. You need to know what to set for 1234 here.
        'I suggest adding it as argument to the method.
        sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@rateid", SqldbType.Int).Value = 1234

        sqlConn.Open()   
        Using myreader As SqlDataReader = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader()
            If myreader.Read() Then
                Label1.Text = myreader("22ktrate").ToString()
                Label2.Text = myreader("21ktrate").ToString()
            End If
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

I made other structural changes to the code, too, *and you should follow this new pattern*. The original code in the question had several less-noticeable issues that could eventually cause user-facing issues, such as failing to close the connection if an exception was thrown.

Finally, I saw this in the comments:

> i just want last row two selected column values from sql database

There is no ORDER BY clause in that select statement. Without an ORDER BY clause, the order for the rows is undefined and Sql Server is free to give you the rows in any order it finds convenient. There is no meaningful definition for "last row". If this matters, you must add an ORDER BY clause to the sql statement... at which point, you are better off *inverting the order* and only taking the *first* record, rather than iterating the entire result set. If it doesn't matter... you're still better of just taking the first row vs iterating the entire set. In either case, you could also add a TOP 1 to the SQL command — if it's even possible to have more than one record match the `max(rateid)`.

Comment: Does a "2" count as a letter in Unicode for the identifier "22ktrate" or does it need square brackets?

Comment: @AndrewMorton  It probably needs square brackets. They certainly never hurt, so I'll add them to the answer.

Comment: I tried it - the square brackets are definitely required.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I can see that you're already using the reader to check if it had rows.
Just set the last value AFTER the reader has read.

This assumes that the `Order by` of your SQL query is correct (`asc` or `desc`)

Change this part:
    myreader = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader()

```
myreader.Read()

If myreader.HasRows Then

    Label1.Text = myreader.Item("22ktrate")
    Label2.Text = myreader.Item("21ktrate")


End If

sqlConn.Close()
```

to

```
While myreader.Read()
   Label1.Text = myreader.Item("22ktrate")
   Label2.Text = myreader.Item("21ktrate")
End While

sqlConn.Close()
```

Comment: This sounds like what he's asking for based on the comment, but I'm not sure it's right because the max(rateid) = @rateid in the sql is likely to limit this to one record in the results. Additionally, there's no ORDER BY clause at all, meaning "last" is completely undefined. So even if this is what he wants, he'll still need to add an ORDER BY clause, at which point he's likely better off just inverting the order and only reading the first record.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn that's true.. maybe throw me a cookie though since I tried? :P